# saving xargs ouput from multi files to one file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xargs, stdin

I have these three text files :

```
#1.txt
hey stackoverflow
```

```
#2.txt   
hey stackexchange
```

```
#3.txt
hello world
```

I am using this command to list the last 3 files in my dir and then `cat` them and then save all the output from 3 files to one file (`all.txt`)

Command :

```
ls -alth *txt | head -3 | xargs -n1 cat
```

How I can redirect the output to a file ??

Comment: The same way you redirect any output to a file: `... | xargs -n1 cat > outputfile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `-l` (for long listing) option of `ls` makes no sense here as you want only the file names (same for `-h` (a GNU extension to report sizes in *human* format) which goes with it).

Using `xargs`'s default way to split `ls` is also incorrect as that would break on file names containing blanks, newline, quotes, backslashes...

Using the `-a` option is also pointless as it's the shell that computes the list of files by expanding the `*txt` globs here, not `ls`, and glob expansions don't include hidden files by default.

You'd want (on a recent GNU system and with the GNU shell (bash)):

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -Ltd --zero -- !(all.)txt | head -zn3 | xargs -r0 cat -- > all.txt
```

(also set the `dotglob` option if you want hidden files to be considered).

Adding:

- the `-L` option to `ls` so that for files of  type symlink, it's the modification time of the target of the symlink that is taken into account
- `-d` because if some of those files are of type *directory*, you don't want `ls` to  list their contents.
- `--zero`/`-z`/`-0` to work with NUL-delimited  records, NUL being the only character that cannot occur in a file path.
- `!(all.)txt` instead of `*txt` to make sure `all.txt` is not included in the list which could cause an infinite loop filling up your disks.
- `-r` option to `xargs` to avoid running `cat` if no file was found.
- `--` to mark the end of options, so file names starting with `-` are not treated as options by `ls` or `cat`.

Or with zsh instead of bash and on any system:

```
set -o extendedglob
cat -- (^all.)txt(-.om[1,3]) > all.txt
```

Where:

- `^x` is the zsh equivalent of ksh's `!(x)` (bash supports a subset of ksh's extended glob operators with its `extglob` option)
- `-` for the equivalent of `-L`
- `.` to restrict to *regular* files (or symlinks to regular files), excluding directories, fifos, devices...
- `om` equivalent of `-t` to order by modification time.
- `[1,3]` like `head -zn3` limits to the first 3.
- if the glob doesn't match any file, the command is not run and an error is returned (and contrary to the bash command above, `all.txt` is not created/truncated).

If you want hidden files  to be considered, add the `D` *glob qualifier* (`cat -- (^all.)txt(D-.om[1,3]) > all.txt`)